# How could an ability to project fire from your body occur plausibly?

Tags: biology, physics, super-powers, mutation

Imagine the ability to shoot long streams of hot fire like a USM2 flamethrower from the palms of your hands. or shooting them out of your feet so you can push yourself off of the floor. An answer with a mix of biology and physics would be great. Maybe it would be a sort of liquid or gas idk.

Comment: There are many dragon fire related questions already on the site you could look through that would help, some involve combustible substances and other involve an electric organ for a spark and a propellant, one example https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/dragon-fire-as-powerful-as-possible

Comment: btw your question reminds me of the anime enen no shouboutai (fire force), the main character boosts fire from his feet and the whole anime is fire projectile based.

Comment: Chop off the offending limb and replace it with the necessary hardware.

Comment: @Halfthawed I don't see the reason for automutilation when I just could ride the necessary hardware and descend from it at the destination. Who knows, maybe I can even let others use the same hardware, for increased economic efficiency ;p

Comment: (eye-roll) - things like this question is what one gets from minds force-fed by Marvel. I can only wish the questions on the line of "How can my superhero evolve naturally?" or "How can I obliterate a planet with a AAA battery powered gizmo?" would stop, but I realize that's a fool's dream. The more the time passes, I get to appreciate better the masters of the hard scifi of the past.

Comment: Hey, DEMI, before you ask, how about you compute the energy/power of such flames and compare with the same a biological organism is able to _plausibly_ withstand?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi but you cant fault those that want to learn and don't realise they should check the massive resource first, I am one of those noobs that only from asking questions on here for my story has learned how to advance.

Comment: @RandySavage mea culpa for venting my frustration. I could get an excuse by blaming cabin fever but, while it plays a role, that wouldn't be actually true.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi indeed squire and all respect to your contributions helping me in the past, cabin fever? sir I have been accustomed to that kind of life for many years, a master hermit with much to learn,,, btw help me with my recent questions pls, not to detract from this gent trying to learn.

Comment: @RandySavage `cabin fever?` A.k.a. "social distancing" or whatever the thing to slow the covid19 spreading is called in your neck of the woods. Including the work-from-home part. Not all of us get to adjust gracefully to it. Age may be another excuse; that's the thing when one realizes that the time left to live is less than the time they lived through and this is getting worse as the time passes.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I guess sometimes the really deep questions on here bring light to all those questions that make us think about our life, just stay safe prepare, but don't over prepare and f over others leaving them short.

Comment: If alternatives to hands are permitted, males could emit well-aimed napalm-urine.

Comment: @user535733 `napalm-urine` Yeap, _there_'s the solution. You only need to show why would a biological body get rid of energetic substances as a waste (like urine) which they synthesized from low energy food (those pesky `physics` and `biology` tags)

Comment: Project fire from your feet to fly? I wonder why soldiers with flamethrowers aren't *flying soldiers with flamethrowers*. You'd have to shoot enough flammable liquid out with enough force to counteract your own weight and get off the ground. That's going to be a lot of liquid, apparently *flammable liquid*, almost certainly enough to create a large and lethal for all parties explosion.

Comment: @Adrian... Rigel had Napalm Urine in Farscape after eating an epic Space Turnip, lol.

Comment: @DariusArcturus a DOI citation wouldn't hurt. Was it independently reproduced by other labs? ;)

Comment: @RandySavage exactly like fire force

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the most healthy explanation of fiery flight, but maybe this could be helpful (or at the very least, fun to know)

Using a kerosene fuel:

-Kerosene is about 3.09kg per gallon at 60*F

-If we replaced all the water volume in your body (or your body mutated to replace it somehow for some reason) with kerosine you’d have 50.7kg of kerosine in your body

-The average COMPLETELY DEHYDRATED person weighs ~34kg

-To fly at the average sprinting speed of a human you’d fly 9m/s

Using the equation for the conservation of momentum we can calculate...

34kg • 9m/s = -50.7kg • v

...one would need to expunge all the kerosene in their body at ~6m/s (~13.5mph) to launch your dehydrated, shriveled corpse into the air to fly at sprinting speed! Isn’t that fun and not at all related to the question you asked, let alone useful?

PS, I have no idea how burning the kerosene as it is blasted from your corpse would effect the whole deal.

PPS, Sorry for all the useless information!

Comment: So, we engineer a person into a kerosene rocket with a payload of waterless biomass? Nice.

Comment: @BMFForMonica `a payload of waterless biomass`. Not necessarily. I mean, you can even use that waterless biomass [as fuel too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythBusters_(2006_season)#Salami_Rocket) (:grin:)